# Output file is not generating

Tags: sharelatex

I have got one issue with the latex document while compiling. 
The output file is not generating and showing the error message as 
"Undefined control sequence." in so many lines shown as output.bbl
Main.tex code is shown below

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}}
\usepackage[rawfloats=true]{floatrow} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{title}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{title}
\author{name}
\date{May 2015}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Abstract}
The purpose of 

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
I would like 

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}
\chapter{Research Methodology}
\input{chapters/ResearchMethodology}
\chapter{Literature Review}
\input{chapters/RelatedWorks}
\chapter{Background}
\input{chapters/Background}
\chapter{Prestudy}
\input{chapters/Casestudy}
\chapter{Requirements Specification}
\input{chapters/RequirementSpecification}
\chapter{Implementation}
\input{chapters/Implementation}
\chapter{Evaluation}
\input{chapters/Evaluation}
\chapter{Discussion}
\input{chapters/GeneralDiscussion}
\chapter{Conclusion and Future works}
\input{chapters/Conclusion}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendices}
\input{chapters/appendix}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have some warnings too with errors

[image]

Comment: Your post contains a lot of `\input` ... none of the files is available to us

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the the version of Biber you are using does not work with the version of biblatex you have installed.

Without knowing which version of the two you are actually using the best I can do is suggesting you to update to the last version of Biber (2.1) [here](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) and as it is advised on their website use this last version in combination with biblatex 3.0:

> Biber 2.1 is now released. It should be used in conjunction with biblatex 3.0".

Make sure to update also the biblatex package if you do not already have version 3.0.